# Difference between li.current and li.active

Tags: jquery, css, joomla

I'm using a template which uses JQuery. The "Inspect Element" of Firefox shows:

```
<ul>
    <li class="index current active">
    ...
```

I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463271/joomla-how-to-keep-main-menu-item-highlighted-while-navigating-through-separate) the following code:

```
li.parent li.current { CSS here } //do things based on the current
 li.active li.active { css here } // add an .active for each level down the hierarchy, for example to affect 3 ways in, require three li.actives in the hierarchical-selector
```

I guest that `li.active` is only for submenus. But I don't have submenus and the following code:

```
li.current { font-size: 10% }
```

Produces the same result than:

```
li.active { font-size: 10% }
```

So what's the difference?

Comment: There's no difference, the CSS you've posted is the same, obviously.  The creator probably added a active class for some reason.

Comment: those not any generic CSS selectors, but classes. So the developer created them. It can mean whatever he wanted it to be.

Comment: The first line asks for `li.current` inside `li.parent`. The second line asks for `li.active` inside `li.active`. JQuery does not define these classes. Not sure if jQueryUI does. In any case, this question cannot be answered in its current state (at the very least, it would need the jQueryUI tag edited in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont have submenu, it doesnt matter. But globally, the class current is on the menu element of the page that you are currently watch while the class active is on every active menu. It mean that if one of its descendant has the class current, is is active.

Example

```
level 1
level 2
    level 2.1
    level 2.2
    level 2.3
        level 2.3.1
level 3
    level 3.1
level 4
```

In this tree, is you are on the page `level 2.3.1`, `level 2.3.1` will have the class current while `level 2, level 2.3 and 2.3.1` will have the class active.

```
level 1
level 2 .active
    level 2.1
    level 2.2
    level 2.3 .active
        level 2.3.1 .current.active
level 3
    level 3.1
level 4
```

It just give the state of the element.

## Note

It is not jQuery that put those classes, it is joomla, this answer is based on the question posted inside your question. Those classes are put on menu element.

Comment: Are you assuming jQueryUI? jQuery does not define these classes.

Comment: @JanDvorak See my note ;) i forgot to mention it.

Comment: oh... perhaps the Joomla tag should be edited into the question, then?

Comment: @JanDvorak Probably, but that was an assumption.

Comment: Actually, the CMS is GetSimple CMS. I guess the template was created for Joomla first @JanDvorak

Comment: @chelder i don't know that CMS, just try to put some sub menues and see what happen..